# Does typeof(myType).TypeHandle use reflection?

Tags: c#

If I wrote this code:

```
typeof(myType).TypeHandle
```

Would it use reflection?

How much different from:

```
Type.GetType(string).TypeHandle
```

is it?

Comment: Some kind of context for your question would make it more useful to the community. I'd like to see a discussion on this (as well as the answer).

Comment: It seems that this is more a definition problem, should we call it reflection or not. What is the real problem behind this question?

Comment: @Deeno: Please consider this the baseline for what is expected of a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it really depends on what you mean by "reflection" - which isn't exactly strictly defined.

There are two parts to using `typeof` in the compiled code. The first is the use of the `ldtoken` which is an IL instruction described like this in the CIL spec:

> The ldtoken instruction pushes a
>   RuntimeHandle for the specified
>   metadata token. The token shall be one
>   of:
>
> - A methoddef, methodref or
>     methodspec: pushes a
>     RuntimeMethodHandle
> - A typedef,
>     typeref, or typespec : pushes a
>     RuntimeTypeHandle
> - A fielddef or
>     fieldref : pushes a RuntimeFieldHandle
>
> The value pushed on the stack can be
>   used in calls to reflection methods in
>   the system class library

After this, a call to `Type.GetTypeFromHandle` is made.

This is all significantly quicker than `Type.GetType(string)` however, if that's what you were concerned with.

EDIT: I just noticed the TypeHandle part of your question. As far as I can see, the MS compiler doesn't optimise away the call to GetTypeFromHandle and then TypeHandle, even though I guess you really only need the `ldtoken` call.

Whether all of this counts as "reflection" or not is up to you...

Comment: Just ran into this while optimizing some heavily used reflection code. There is a significant benefit attached to using `TypeHandle`s over `Type`. It's a bit unfortunate the C# compiler doesn't do it OOB, next best thing is to assign the TypeHandle to a static readonly field. Ugly but gets me the performance benefit. And the scope of static readonly fields matches that of `TypeHandle`s, so there's no worries.